# How to upload image files to different directories dynamically in CKEDITOR which has a Django backend?

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, image-uploading

I am using Filemanager of FCKEditor in my ckeditor to upload and manage image uploads. However in the configuration file(config.py), the upload_to directory path is hardcoded.

```
UserFilesPath = '/userfiles/'
```

and full path for image files is hardcoded as -

```
FileTypesPath['Image'] = UserFilesPath + 'image/'
```

But I want to upload image files to different directories.I will explain -

Every web page of mine has different Ckeditors with unique Ids.Each such CKEDITOR represents a document.I want to upload image of a particular ckeditor to a particular document path.For ex -

```
FilesTypesPath['Image'] = UserFilesPath + 'image/' + 'unique_doc_id/'
```

The unique doc Id will vary for every document.Is there any way around to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Possible answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/52133355/1822062