# ckeditor_uploader Dynamic Image Upload Path

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I have a Django application that requires users to upload multiple images per document. The application has django-ckeditor installed, but the uploaded images end up in the same folder set by the `CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH` setting. I would like the path to be dynamic, based on the URL scheme.

For example, images uploaded to the CKEditor instance on  `https://myapp/report/1/finding/5` should reside in  `/ckeditor_base_path/report/1/finding/5/my_img.png`.

Unfortunately, the URL for the view function that handles setting the path is set by the widget ([CKEditorUploadingWidget](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/blob/master/ckeditor_uploader/widgets.py)) before the view creates a `context` parameter.

I was hoping to send the parameters URL parameters to [ImageUploadView](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/blob/master/ckeditor_uploader/views.py) for processing. Any help or advice on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone else, here's what I did. When users browse, they will be restricted to the folder with the finding images, since they are specific to that part of the report. Similarly, uploading an image will send it to the same folder.

In a nutshell, you have to:

1. Point the CKEditor Uploader URLs to your version of the views
2. Update the CKEditor Uploader widget through the corresponding form views
3. Override the CKEditor Uploader `ImageUploadView`  and `browse` views to create the path you want

### Examples

#### Updated CKEditor URL Paths

```
path('myapp/<int:org_id>/report/<int:report_id>/finding/<int:finding_id>/image/upload', never_cache(ck_views.upload),
path('myapp/<int:org_id>/report/<int:report_id>/finding/<int:finding_id>/images', never_cache(ck_views.browse), name='ckeditor_browse'),
```

#### Widget Update

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        obj = self.get_object()
        if obj is not None:
            context['org'] = obj.report.org.id
            form = FindingForm(instance=obj)
            # Set image browse/upload path
            image_kwargs = {
                'finding_id': obj.id,
                'org_id': obj.report.org.id,
                'report_id': obj.report.id,
            }
            image_browse_path = reverse('ckeditor_browse', kwargs=image_kwargs)
            image_upload_path = reverse('ckeditor_upload', kwargs=image_kwargs)
            form.fields['description'].widget.config['filebrowserBrowseUrl'] = image_browse_path
            form.fields['description'].widget.config['filebrowserUploadUrl'] = image_upload_path
            context['form'] = form
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same problem and looked at your answer, but I think there is a potentially easier solution.

For every 'unique' upload action that is to be performed, create a new config in `settings.py`:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'action_a' : {
        'filebrowserUploadUrl': '/path/to/action/a/handling/view/'
    },
    'action_b' : {
        'filebrowserUploadUrl': '/path/to/action/b/handling/view/'
    }
}
```

When creating your form, set the `config_name` of the `CKEditorUploadingWidget` to the required action.

If you don't need to handle any URL parameters - like in my case, where I just wanted to put files uploaded via a different editor interface in a different directory - then next steps are relatively straightforward. Handle and save the uploaded file in your corresponding view.

If you do need to perform an action based on URL parameters, however, you could examine the `request` in the corresponding view to get the page where the file was uploaded from:

```
referrer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
```

You could then extract the parameters from the URL that you need - in your case the report ID and finding ID - and use them to upload to whatever directory you want.